# Does KOGrid have Aggregates?

Tags: knockout.js, grid, kogrid

Does KOGrid have Aggregates?

I want to show Total, Min, Max under the column.

If not inbuilt is there an easier way to create them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally landed up here

https://github.com/LukePulverenti/KoGrid

Luke Pulverenti has an implementaion of KOGrid with overridden footerTemplate.

I created my own aggregate variables and binded then in footer Template.

Though this is not a very elegant solution..but couldn't do better than this.

Answer (score 0):

The ko.utils closure has some array functions, but its very basic, you can have a look at linqjs

http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

edit: KoGrid itself has no feature for this btw